# How to speed up sequential analysis in R?

Tags: r, performance, loops

I need to sequently analyze a dataset while using subresults of the operations before.

As I am known to R I decided to work with this and one of the solution I tried is using an for loop.

The dataset which I loop through has around 8 million rows with 4 columns.

I use a data.table and the variables are of type character eg. "XXXXXXXXX"

I tried to loop through but it takes approx 0,7 second per cycle from which the "<-" operation takes half a second.

Can anybody recommend a better technique. Potentially rcpp, apply or whatever?

Thx for your support,

Holger

```
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))
library('data.table')    


dt_loop <- data.table(
              paste0("XXXXXXXXXX", 1:80000000),
              paste0("YXXXXXXXXX", 1:80000000),
              paste0("ZXXXXXXXXX", 1:80000000),
              paste0("AXXXXXXXXX", 1:80000000)
      )

    colnames(dt_loop)[colnames(dt_loop)=="V1"] <- "m"
    colnames(dt_loop)[colnames(dt_loop)=="V2"] <- "c"
    colnames(dt_loop)[colnames(dt_loop)=="V3"] <- "ma"
    colnames(dt_loop)[colnames(dt_loop)=="V4"] <- "unused"


    for(i in 1:nrow(dt_loop)){
      m <- dt_loop$m[i]
      c <- dt_loop$m[i]

      if(m %!in% dt_loop$ma[1:i] & c %!in% dt_loop$ma[1:i]){
        dt_loop$ma[i] <- m
      } else { 
        if(m %in% dt_loop$ma[1:i]){
          dt_loop$ma[i] <- m
        } else {
          dt_loop$ma[i] <- c
        }
      } 
    }
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. We don't need all 8 million rows, but we do need something to test with and compare results. It would also be a good idea to describe what you are trying to do in words; there may be better strategies.

Comment: This code seems to start with a dataset where none of the values across four columns are repeated. Then, for each row, we look to see if `m` hasn't occurred up to that point in `ma` (it hasn't) and if `c` hasn't occurred up to that point in `ma` (it hasn't). Given that, replace `ma` with `m` in that row, and repeat. I expect this will result in `ma` being set to `m` for all rows. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a self-join Cartesian product solution. I modified your code to get somewhat meaningful results. I also think that if you have 8 million rows, you're going to have performance troubles when the nth loop depends on the nth before hand.

Changes in data structure:

1. Used `sample` to get some repeats in the data.table
2. Simplified the column names to data.table function `setnames()`
3. Added an ID field
4. Removed unused column.

```
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))
library('data.table')    

# Generate Data -----------------------------------------------------------

set.seed(1)
n_rows <- 10
dt_loop <- data.table(
  sample(paste0("X", 1:n_rows), n_rows, replace = T),
  sample(paste0("Y", 1:n_rows), n_rows, replace = T),
  sample(paste0("X", 1:n_rows), n_rows, replace = T)
)

setnames(dt_loop, c('m', 'c', 'ma'))
dt_loop[, ID := .I]
```

I made significant changes to your loop.

1. Assigned `c <- dt_loop$c[i]` as I don't know what using m there did.
2. Removed the first `if` statement because of the new assignment of `c`.

```
# Original loop with Minor Mod --------------------------------------------

for(i in 1:nrow(dt_loop)){
  m <- dt_loop$m[i]
  c <- dt_loop$c[i] #changed to c instead of m

#Removed first ifelse condition
  #as it didn't make sense as originally constructed

  # if(m %!in% dt_loop$ma[1:i] & c %!in% dt_loop$ma[1:i]){
    # dt_loop$ma2[i] <- m
  # } else {
    if(m %in% dt_loop$ma[1:i]){
      dt_loop$ma2[i] <- m
    } else {
      dt_loop$ma2[i] <- c
    }
  # }
}
dt_loop

      m   c  ma ID ma2
 1:  X3  Y3 X10  1  Y3
 2:  X4  Y2  X3  2  Y2
 3:  X6  Y7  X7  3  Y7
 4: X10  Y4  X2  4 X10
 5:  X3  Y8  X3  5  X3
 6:  X9  Y5  X4  6  Y5
 7: X10  Y8  X1  7 X10
 8:  X7 Y10  X4  8  X7
 9:  X7  Y4  X9  9  X7
10:  X1  Y8  X4 10  X1
```

The self-join seems to be faster than the loop when I up the rows to 10,000, but it still slows down. Of note is that you can see when there is duplication with `ma` because the cartesian product expands the results so you get `N == 2`.

I believe that there are ways to get the self-join to work so that you only get the Nth row which should relieve some pressure.

```
dt_loop[dt_loop
        , on = .(ID <= ID
                 , ma = m)
        , .(.N
            ,i.ma2 #for comparison - remove
            ,ma3 = ifelse(is.na(x.ID), i.c, i.m)
            ,i.ID, i.m, i.c, i.ma
            ,x.ID, x.m, x.c, x.ma 
        )
        , by = .EACHI
        , allow.cartesian = T]

    ID  ma N i.ma2 ma3 i.ID i.m i.c i.ma x.ID  x.m  x.c x.ma
 1:  1  X3 0    Y3  Y3    1  X3  Y3  X10   NA <NA> <NA> <NA>
 2:  2  X4 0    Y2  Y2    2  X4  Y2   X3   NA <NA> <NA> <NA>
 3:  3  X6 0    Y7  Y7    3  X6  Y7   X7   NA <NA> <NA> <NA>
 4:  4 X10 1   X10 X10    4 X10  Y4   X2    1   X3   Y3  X10
 5:  5  X3 2    X3  X3    5  X3  Y8   X3    2   X4   Y2   X3
 6:  5  X3 2    X3  X3    5  X3  Y8   X3    5   X3   Y8   X3
 7:  6  X9 0    Y5  Y5    6  X9  Y5   X4   NA <NA> <NA> <NA>
 8:  7 X10 1   X10 X10    7 X10  Y8   X1    1   X3   Y3  X10
 9:  8  X7 1    X7  X7    8  X7 Y10   X4    3   X6   Y7   X7
10:  9  X7 1    X7  X7    9  X7  Y4   X9    3   X6   Y7   X7
11: 10  X1 1    X1  X1   10  X1  Y8   X4    7  X10   Y8   X1
```